Substance painter crazy blotches on object after baking in Substance Painer
Substance painter crazy blotches on object after baking in Substance Painer
What I am trying to do is export a fbx object from Blender 4.21 into Substance Painter. I thought the issue was with the UV mapping in Blender, but they seem okay to me.



Since you haven't given us any details of your Blender setup or added any images to your question it's impossible to give an answer to that! However you might start by reading through  .fbx export why there are no materials or textures if you're trying to export textures created using nodes in Blender in FBX format.
